# wget saving file with incorrect name/type. Why?

Tags: bash, unix, authentication, wget

I have got a wget running to a remote server. I am aiming to save the 9000 files on my server, as the only way I can get them is on GET request at a time due to ridiculous security measures.

So I am running :

C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies c
ookies.txt \ -p https://username:password@website.webpage.com/folder/document/download/1type=attachment

Now, navigating to the above URL in a browser will allow me to download the webpage as a .html file. However, when I run this command, I am saving the file as

```
1@type=attachment
```

and it is creating a new chain of folders `/website.webpage.com/folder/document/download/` which contains the file.

What have I misunderstood/called wrongly here?

Comment: is there supposed to be a space between the c and o of cookies ?Also why would you expect it not save as the same file ? Finally this has nothing to do with unix or bash :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--content-disposition` option to try and honour that header (which is probably what your browser is doing).

From the `wget` man page:

> --content-disposition
>
> If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for "Content-Disposition" headers is enabled. This can
>   currently result in extra round-trips to the server for a "HEAD"
>   request, and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is
>   not currently enabled by default.

Comment: You are a beautiful person <3. Thank you.